# Insert values in mysql table with post method

Tags: php, mysqli

Currently I am having some trouble to insert some values in MySQL.

I have a table: `bidder`

```
Columns
id   type  run_id   min_bid   max_bid
```

I am having trouble inserting the `min_bid` and `max_bid`. I am getting these with the post method. Point being is that as I have different bidder types, I may need multiple values for 1 bidder or I may need only 1 value.

I made the post value different so I can distinguish the differences for when I need to save 1 value or 2 values.

This is a `var_dump()` of the `$_POST`:

```
array(5) { 
     ["get_bid0"] => string(1) "5" 
     ["get_bid1"] => string(1) "6" 
     ["get_bid_low2"] => string(1) "7" 
     ["get_bid_high2"]=> string(2) "11" 
     ["get_bids"]=> string(8) "Set Bids" 
}
```

So the table `bidder` has to be saved like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| id   | type      | run_id | min_bid | max_bid |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|  1   | steadybid |  1     |   5     |    5    |
|  2   | steadybid |  1     |   6     |    6    |
|  3   | random    |  1     |   7     |    11   |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

All but the `min_bid` and `max_bid` are already set.

All I can think of are a whole lot of if statements.

Note: the id's of the bidders may not be sequential, because bidders can be deleted through a button click. So after bidder id 3, there is a possibility that the next id would be 5 instead of 4.

Any ideas?

Comment: use the *id* field as `auto_increment`

Comment: Done that. I am creating a simulation, where users can delete the last created bidder. The auto_increment remembers it's last position. That's why a 'gap' can be created and I cannot user 'alter table', since I am using an innoDB

Comment: I think u can not set to auto increment without making it key

Comment: I know. I already made it key.

Comment: @Ajaxkevi keeping in mind your requirement, u can't set it to key and auto increment because if you do that it ll not be in sequential order. i.e if some one deletes the third row, next will be id = 4 .which you don't want. So my suggestion ll be, keep your id field unique and every time you made an insertion check for the latest id field in desc order and increment it by 1 and insert.

Comment: Solved it myself but thanks for your suggestion @dkakoti. Won't be of use for me, but sure it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own answer partly:

Had to do a foreach loop for each bidder id containing the same run id:

```
$strSql = 'select id from bidder where run_id='. $this->getRunId().';';
$arrIdBidders = $objDatabase->queryresult($strSql);
```

I had to change the name for steadybids to the same name as the random bids in the post, so I could use the following foreach loops.

```
foreach($arrIdBidders as $bidderkey => $key)  {
            $biddernumber = $bidderkey + 1;

            $strSql = 'update bidder set min_bid = '.$arrBids['get_bid_low'.$biddernumber].'
 where id = '. $arrIdBidders[$bidderkey]['id'].';';

            $blnOke = $objDatabase->query($strSql);
        }

        foreach($arrIdBidders as $bidderkey => $key)  {
            $biddernumber = $bidderkey + 1;

            $strSql = 'update bidder set max_bid = '.$arrBids['get_bid_high'.$biddernumber].' where id = '. $arrIdBidders[$bidderkey]['id'].';';

            $blnOke = $objDatabase->query($strSql);
        }
```

Hope it helps someone and thanks for thinking along.